# Linking nightmare on my street

Tags: php, html

```
<img src="…/<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>">
```

gives me this. It’s actually the one I want only without the `…`
http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/.../artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg

```
 <img src="../<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>">
```

give me this
http://markdinwiddie.com/artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg

```
<img src="/../<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>">
```

gives me this
http://markdinwiddie.com/artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg

and

```
<img src="/…/<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>">
```

gives me this
http://markdinwiddie.com/.../artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg

What I need is
http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg

Who knows the order of dots and slashes?

Comment: +1 For an awesome title!

Comment: -1 for an utterly confusing question. And the title.

Comment: Yep, the question seems to be incomplete/messed up.

Comment: What don't you understand? I am trying to get  markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg by passing a PHP variable.<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>

Comment: I know it should be easy!!! But it's NOT working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the webpage is within the PHP2012 folder: `http://markdinwiddie.com/PHP2012/`

and your image is in `artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg` within the PHP2012 folder

can't you just do `<img src="<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>">`

Comment: drop the forward slash at the beginning `<img src="<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>">`

Comment: WOW! I thought I tried that one!!! I guess I was just using echo "$ArtFilePath" and echo $ArtFilePath But thanks a million md, it works!

Comment: Note that using `<?php echo "$ArtFilePath"; ?>` is plain stupid. You should use `<?php echo $ArtFilePath; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Since `$artFilePath == "artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg"`, you want either:

#### Relative urls

Provided your php file is within `/PHP2012/` this will work. It will even work if you rename the directory

```php
<img src="<?php echo $ArtFilePath ?>" />
```

Which outputs

```
<img src="artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg" />
```

#### Absolute urls

```php
<img src="/PHP2012/<?php echo $ArtFilePath ?>" />
```

Which outputs

```
<img src="/PHP2012/artwork/Drawings/Boy.jpg" />
```